# React Native Expo VirtualizedList how to use scrollToEnd method?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use a scrollToEnd() method on VirtualizedList. But interestingly I cannot find any example on the internet explaining how to use methods with VirtualizedList.

I tried to use it like below, but obviously it didn't work

```
<VirtualizedList
          data={serverData}
          initialNumToRender={4}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          getItemCount={getItemCount}
          getItem={getItem}
          ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
          scrollToEnd={{ animated: true }}
        />
```

Comment: check new solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scrollToEnd` function is inherited from `ScrollView` by `VirtualizedList`. It is a function, not a prop.

You need to create a reference to the list component and call the function using this reference. This can be done as follows.

```js
const listRef = useRef(null);

<VirtualizedList
    ref= {listRef}
    onContentSizeChange= {()=> listRef.current.scrollToEnd()} 
/>
```

The above code scrolls to the end of the list when the content size of its data changes. However, you can call the `scrollToEnd` function whenever you want to.

Answer (score 0):

`VirtualizedList`expose `scrollToEnd` as method not props. You have to use React Ref to access it.

```js
const listRef = React.useRef(null)

// Scroll to list end - Call this function after add new items to list for example
const scrollToListEnd = ()=> listRef.current?.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })

<VirtualizedList
  data={serverData}
  initialNumToRender={4}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
  getItemCount={getItemCount}
  getItem={getItem}
  ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
  ref={listRef}
/>;
```

Comment: This one does not work